# Not able to read anything from serial using pyserial

Tags: pyserial

I have written a python script to communicate to my RS232 device,
after execution i am able to write to terminal but i am not getting any output.If i open my teraterm i am able to see cmnd passed thru pyserial(with out any output print).
**code :**
    import serial

```
port = "COM1"
baud = 115200

ser = serial.Serial(port, baud, timeout=1)

if ser.isOpen():
     print(ser.name + ' is open...')


cmd = input("Enter command or 'exit':")

if cmd == 'exit':
   ser.close()
   exit()
else:
   ser.write(cmd.encode()+b'\r\n')
   out = ser.read()
   print('Receiving...'+out.decode())
```

**following is the output from console :**

```
COM1 is open...
Enter command or 'exit':ls
Receiving...l
```

Comment: So you can read cmd it seems, and you typed ls?  The output was only l?  Is it always the case that the ser.read() only gets 1 character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Receiving...l
```

This is what I'd expect from your program. The default value for [`read()`](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial_api.html?highlight=.read#serial.Serial.read)'s size parameter is 1. This means that one byte will be read.

If the other end echoes your input `'ls'`, the first byte will be an `'l'`.

Try the [`readline()`](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/shortintro.html?highlight=readline#readline) method (don't forget to add a timeout, or it might block forever). Or handle the protocol some other way, by repeatedly calling `read()`, for example.

Comment: @joel,@Andé thank you for guidance.
m able to read "cmd" using read() and readline(),but my doubt is ,when i pass some command to my RS232 ,should i not get the desired output from console (i.e if pass cmd=pwd,should i not get present working directory or list of files if i pass cmd=ls) or am i interpreting working of pyserial in a wrong way ,or do i need some executable on by board to communicate.